# Does Azure SQL "Elastic Database Query" allow connections to an on-premises SQL Server database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I would like to query an on-premises SQL Server from an Azure SQL Database. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31129753/2363207) answer seems to indicate that I can do just that with the "Elastic Database Query" feature.

However, everything I have read about "Elastic Database Query" only mentions connecting to another *Azure* SQL Database, not an on-premises SQL Server database.

I tried using the "Elastic Database Query" functionality by running these statements one after the other:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'MY_SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD';  

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL SSDB_On_Premises_Credentials    
WITH IDENTITY = 'MY_USERNAME',  
SECRET = 'MY_OTHER_SUPER_SECRET_PASSWORD';  

CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE SSDB_On_Premises WITH   
    (TYPE = RDBMS,   
    LOCATION = 'the.path.to.my.on.premises.database',   
    DATABASE_NAME = 'MyDatabaseName',    
    CREDENTIAL = SSDB_On_Premises_Credentials          
) ;     

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE USER(
    ID INT NOT NULL, 
    FIRSTNAME NVarchar(255),
    LASTNAME NVarchar(255) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = SSDB_On_Premises 
);

SELECT * FROM USER;
```

However, I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL
>   Server)

This might be a problem with the configuration settings on my on-premises SQL Server, but I'm guessing its more likely that "Elastic Database Query" just doesn't connect to an on-premises data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  The doc for [CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) specifies that the target must be Azure SQL Database for an RDBMS external data source:

```
-- Elastic Database query only: a remote database on Azure SQL Database as data source   
-- (only on Azure SQL Database)  
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE data_source_name  
    WITH (   
        TYPE = RDBMS,  
        LOCATION = '<server_name>.database.windows.net',  
        DATABASE_NAME = '<Remote_Database_Name>',  
        CREDENTIAL = <SQL_Credential>  
    )  
[;]
```

Azure SQL Database Managed Instance supports Linked Server connections to SQL Server:

> Linked servers
>
> Linked servers in Managed Instance support limited
> number of targets:  Supported targets: SQL Server and SQL Database Not
> supported targets: files, Analysis Services, and other RDBMS.

[Azure SQL Database Managed Instance T-SQL differences from SQL Serve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance-transact-sql-information)

Also Managed Instance supports running on a private VNet, from which it's reasonable to connect to on-premesis SQL Server instances.  Azure SQL Database would have no way to communicate with your on-premesis servers.

Answer (score 2):

Elastic database queries work between Azure SQL Databases and to query Azure SQL Data Warehouse only. From an architecture point of view on the scenario you describe,  Azure would be relying on a server outside of its infrastructure to satisfy a query, if elastic queries were allowing creating external data sources to on-premises SQL Server instances. A better architecture may be replicating the on-premises database to a hub database on Azure SQL using SQL Data Sync and then create elastic queries using that hub database. Even from a performance point of view makes more sense, since queries won't be executing against your on-premises databases and latency will be less a factor.